# Websockets with cordova doesn't work on ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ipad, websocket

I'm trying to implement WebSockets in JS with Cordova. I don't use any plugins, I do this with the native WebSockets of JS. Basically, my apps connect to the back end, send a message and then wait for the response. This works fine on Chrome / Firefox but when I install it on my iPad the front-end WebSockets never connects to the back-end.

So i tried to add some content policy in my meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: file: ws: wss: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data: ; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' ws: ;">
```

the websocket is created and used like this:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://backEndIP:port/')
ws.send('/skeleton/last')
  ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    resolve(event.data);
  }
```

I don't know what i can be missing.

**EDIT**

I added `<access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media='true' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' />`
 in config.xml but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe disable firewall ? are you sure port used is open ? try to ping your sever to test if you device can connect to it

Comment: My server is working fine since the websockets are working when i preview the apps in an internet browser. So i'm pretty sure that the port is opened too. There is no firewall on iPad (i checked just now)

Comment: i added the ip of my backend aswell after the ws:, so my meta tag looks like this now: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' connect-src 'self' ws://192.168.8.1:9988/ ;">` i also tried several plugins but this still doesn't work... I know that websockets are working fine on Safari since i tested it. I'm really lost there

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add `backEndIP` to your cordova whitelist in config.xml.

See documentation here : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Comment: Can you browse to the server from the iPad, perhaps put a test web page onto the server and see if you can get to it from the device to verify the iPad can actually see the device on the network